# Map field values in Dataset using Spark SQL in JAVA

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

In my dataset before I write to elasticsearch I need to map certain values of a column and replace them such as

- "REJECT" to "PENDING",
- "UNKNOWN" to "FAILED" etc..

```
  Dataset<Row> finalData = data.select(
                data.col("cus_ref").as("key"),
                functions.struct(
                        data.col("username").as("user_id"),
                        data.col("channelId").as("channel"),
                        data.col("country_code").as("country"),
                        data.col("status").as("latest_status"),
                        data.col("acc_number").as("account"),
                        data.col("amt").as("amount"),
                        data.col("currency"),
                        data.col("processing_date"),
                        data.col("sub_date").as("received_time"),
                        data.col("product_code").as("product"),
                        data.col("name")).as("summary"));
```

For data.col("status") how do I map the values and replace them on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'when-otherwise' clauses:

```
val updateDF = finalData.withColumn("latest_status", 
     when(col("latest_status") === "REJECT", "PENDING")
    .when(col("latest_status") === "UNKNOWN", "FAILED")
    .otherwise("foobar"))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Doesn't work the same way in JAVA API.
"The method when(Column, Object) in the type functions is not applicable for the arguments (boolean, String)". Not able to place any column condition inside when.

Comment: Try using this https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Spark-Dataframe-Query-not-working/m-p/161147 as a guideline (modify the columns' names). Update me if necessary :-)